# Find velocity of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[image]

I'm beginner at physics but I have tried :
1) $Ma=Mg-T$ and $Ma=T$ but doesn't seem promising as we have to find velocity
2) Conservation of energy but I'm totally lost, well initially only the block has potential energy and I don't know what to take finally (should we consider the rotational of ball or how)

Comment: Note that rope tension on both sides of the rigid body pulley are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conservation of energy should work. Remember:

-the cylinder (or sphere?) of radius 2R has two kinetic energy terms - one due to rotational kinetic energy about its center of mass, and one due to the translation of the center of mass.

-the pulley of radius R has rotational kinetic energy, but no translational kinetic energy.

-the weight has translational kinetic energy.

-if the cylinder rolls without slipping and the pulley wheel turns without the rope slipping, then their angular velocities and the linear speed of the rope are linked by their radii, respectively. This allows you to write the kinetic energy of the entire system in terms of M, R, and v only - no omegas (angular velocities) left.

If the weight falls a distance h, you should be able to calculate how much energy has been added to the system, and using conservation of energy, the velocity of the weight as a function of h.